# How to reduce width of buttons inside table cell?

Tags: html, css

I want to reduce the size of my buttons to match the size of the text. I'm refering to:

**1) the blue button "Pagar con Tarjeta" and

2) to the orange button "Pagar con Efectivo".**

I've applied a `width60` class to the `button` element, that is a `width:60%` class.

[image]

But it is not working.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/agzvGe

Comment: Like this ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zVxrGx

Comment: use `display:block` and `width:auto` in your button css

Comment: @weegee yes the blue button on top of the orange one. And both centered.

Comment: @ArchinModi could you provide a codepen?

Comment: @OmarGonzales please check [Demo](https://codepen.io/archinmodi/pen/mZyVEp)

Comment: @ArchinModi I'd like to have the blue button on top of the yellow one. could you fix that please?

Comment: @OmarGonzales, you need to set same width or only need to set first button ?

Comment: @ArchinModi same with, even with the "Seguir comprando" button, if possible.

Comment: @OmarGonzales can you check demo again. i have fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way can be to wrap one of the buttons in a div and give it margin to achieve what you want

```html
<div class="tops">
   <button id="buyButton" class="btn-azul  my_custom_btn margin-bottom2 width60">Pagar con Tarjeta</button>
</div>
<button id="depositButton" class="btn-naranja my_custom_btn  width60" checked>Pagar con Efectivo</button>
```

Yes, because `div` is an block element, causes the other button to go down
And define `.tops` like (for bottom margin)

```css
.tops{
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Also, remember that `display:inline-block` and `width:auto` makes the div according to the content in the div and for every element. So for your buttons I just did this.

```css
.width60 {
  width: auto !important;
  display:inline-block !important;
}
```

`!important` to overide other css rules. To achieve same width in both of the buttons, just change `width:auto` to something numerical like

```css
.width60 {
  width: 55% !important;
  display:inline-block !important;
}
```

The code becomes like this

```css
/* BOTONES */
.as-console-wrapper { display:none !important;  }
button.btn-azul {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #5ba4e6;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .09) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
}

.width60 {
  width: 55% !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

button.btn-azul:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #6DB3F0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .09) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
}

button.btn-naranja {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #ffa31a;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: -10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .09) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
}

button.btn-naranja:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FFAC2F;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .09) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .09) 100%);
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  padding: 22px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
}

.tops {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.width40 {
  width: 40%
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="Stickers Gallito Perú">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="fGkwUY2RcijkVzB6DiwIuAToP1y5xw8ECXQQabRAOIM" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/custom.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/home.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/navbar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/header.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/preloader.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/loader.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/footer.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/size-quantity-styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/img/gallito_favicon.png" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/footer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/js/size-quantity.js"></script>

  <!-- Incluyendo Culqi Checkout -->
  <script src="https://checkout.culqi.com/js/v3"></script>
  <title>Stickers Gallito</title>


  <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
  <script>
    (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
      w[l] = w[l] || [];
      w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js'
      });
      var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s),
        dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
      j.async = true;
      j.src =
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
      f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
    })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-TPXWL88');
  </script>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->



</head>

<body>
  <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
  <noscript>
    <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TPXWL88"
            height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</noscript>
  <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

  <div class="general-container">

  </div>





  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-bg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">&emsp;&emsp;<img src="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/img/stickers_gallito_logo.png" width="20px" height="30px"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/stickers">Stickers <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>












      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/carrito_de_compras/"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"
                                                    style="color:white !important;"></i> ( 3)</a>

        </li>

        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> ogonzales</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a href="/ordenes/historial_de_compras/" class="dropdown-item">Historial de compras</a>
          </div>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/salir/">Salir <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>













  <br>
  <br>

  <script>
    Culqi.publicKey = 'pk_live_6qebYEJ2CZ82DsGU';
  </script>

  <script>
    Culqi.settings({
      title: 'Stickers Gallito Store',
      currency: 'PEN',
      description: 'Stickers varios',
      amount: 67900
    });
  </script>





  <div class="container">
    <br>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="text-center my_title">
          Tu carrito de compras
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center">
        <table class="table my_custom_table">
          <thead class="my_custom_thead">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="5">
                Tus items
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>





            <tr>
              <td>
                <a href="cart_item.product.get_absolute_url"><img src="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/product_images/pug3.jpg" alt="" class="float-left rounded" width="90" height="90"></a>
              </td>
              <td class="text-left">
                <b>Stickers semitroquelados</b>
                <br> Tamaño: 5cm x 5cm
                <br> Cantidad: 1000
              </td>
              <td>
                S/650

                <a href="/carrito_de_compras/full_remove/6/" class="custom_icon"><i
                                    class="fas fa-trash-alt custom_icon"></i></a>
              </td>
            </tr>








            <!-- MOSTRAR SAMPLE_ITEMS IN CART_DETAIL -->





            <tr>
              <td>
                <a href="cart_item.product.get_absolute_url"><img src="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/sample_images/cat.png" alt="" class="float-left rounded" width="90" height="90"></a>
              </td>
              <td class="text-left">
                <p class="margin-bottom0"><b>Sobre con muestras</b></p>
                <p class="margin-top0 margin-bottom0">Cantidad: 5 stickers</p>
                <p class="margin-top0 margin-bottom0">Tamaño: varios</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>S/5

                  <a href="/carrito_de_compras/full_remove_sample/41/" class="custom_icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt custom_icon"></i></a>
                </p>
              </td>
              <td></td>

            </tr>




            <tr>
              <td>
                <a href="cart_item.product.get_absolute_url"><img src="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/sample_images/pug3.jpg" alt="" class="float-left rounded" width="90" height="90"></a>
              </td>
              <td class="text-left">
                <p class="margin-bottom0"><b>Stickers redondeados de muestra</b></p>
                <p class="margin-top0 margin-bottom0">Cantidad: 10 stickers</p>
                <p class="margin-top0 margin-bottom0">Tamaño: 13cm x 13cm</p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p>S/9

                  <a href="/carrito_de_compras/full_remove_sample/42/" class="custom_icon"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt custom_icon"></i></a>
                </p>
              </td>
              <td></td>

            </tr>



          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 text-center">

        <table class="table my_custom_table">

          <thead class="my_custom_thead">

            <tr>
              <th>
                Checkout
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tboyd>
            <tr>
              <td>
                Por favor, revise su Carrito de Compras antes de proceder con el pago de la orden
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-left">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-6">
                    Total: S/664<br> Costo de envío: S/15<br> Descuento: <span class="savings"><b>S/0</b></span><br> A pagar: <strong>S/679</strong><br>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-6">
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" id="user_cupon" style="display: inline-block; height: 36px;" placeholder="Ingrese cupón">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="cuponButton" style="display: inline-block; height: 35px;">Enviar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
              <td class="text-left">
                <b>Dirección de envío:</b>
                <select type="text" id="ShippingAddress">
                  <option value="" selected>
                  </option>
                  <option value="">
                  </option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <!-- <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <b>Seleccione método de pago:</b>
                            <br>
                            <p></p>
                            <input class="pago-tarjeta" type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" /> Pago con Tarjeta de
                            Crédito o Débito
                            <br>
                            <input class="pago-deposito" type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" checked />
                            Depósito en efectivo
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <p class="pago-deposito-detalle"><i>Después de dar click en el botón de Pagar,
                                    se le mostrarán <b>las cuentas bancarias</b> a las cuales deberá depositar.</i>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr> -->
            <tr>
              <td>




                <div class="tops"><button id="buyButton" class="btn-azul  my_custom_btn margin-bottom2 width60">Pagar con Tarjeta
                              </button></div>

                <button id="depositButton" class="btn-naranja my_custom_btn  width60" checked>Pagar con
                                Efectivo
                            </button>



                <br>
                <br>
                <a href="/" class="width60 btn btn-secondary btn-block my_custom_btn">Seguir
                                comprando</a>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </tboyd>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ty. could you make the buttons the same width? Even the "Seguir comprando" button?

Comment: You have this class `.as-console-wrapper { display:none !important;  }` but don't see you use it on the html.

Comment: ah. This is to hide the annoying console which is by default on StackOverflow. Nothing to worry about. You can remove it safely @OmarGonzales